# How does Hangfire store call backs?

Tags: c#, hangfire

Given this code...

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Recurring!"),
    Cron.Daily);
```

How does Hangfire store the code to call daily such that it can run it in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is reflection en serialization, but hangfire has a Github repository and I think the most relevant pieces of codes can be found here.
https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Common/Job.cs

remark from the code

> The ability to serialize an action is the cornerstone of 
>      marshalling it outside of a current process boundaries. We are leaving 
>      behind all the tricky features, e.g. serializing lambdas with their
>      closures or so, and considering a simple method call information as 
>      a such an action, and using reflection to perform it.